# Python Threading : How to wake up a python slave thread if data comes in through the socket it manages or master thread adds job in queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I don't want it to be allocated to CPU only to realize nothing happened. My current idea (which I don't like) is to wait on the queue with a timeout of around 60 seconds. If no order comes by then, check the socket with a select. (The socket is blocking. And there will be on average 1 request/minute.)

How good is this idea in terms of performance? Will it scale well with say 200 threads?

I don't want to throw threads away for a pure event-driven solution, but wouldn't mind simple callbacks.

Comment: `Queue` module is basics, the rest requires more explanation. Why not to use select directly (it doesn't need CPU)? Why not to call `recv` directly from all threads? This question is very vague to suggest anything.

Comment: How can I make it more specific? I avoided recv() to ensure my socket doesn't keep the thread blocked while tasks are queuing up. There might never be any data. And select, when should I call it? before or after waiting on queue?

Comment: But blocking a thread is exactly what you need: do not consume CPU until some data arrives from the network, process it, issue next read() and wait until further incoming messages.

Comment: `Will it scale well with say 200 threads?` -- this is unanswerable without knowing nature of requests and their arrival laws. It may scale for 200 rq/s which take 10ms to handle, but not for 2k rq/s which take 1ms (larger overheads!). Plus GIL is dangerous beast. The devil is hiding in details...

Comment: @void, but messages can come from both network and task queue.

Comment: @myaut, edited the question.

Comment: You can replace task queue with another network socket: define serialization / deserealization for tasks and send them as network messages via AF_UNIX socket. Then you can check blocking select which will wake up the thread whenever task or network data arrives.